# Removing the hardcoded urls from spock test case in post request

Tags: spring, groovy, spock

I have written the basic spring Spock test and I am able to successfully do it but the point is that as rite now the URLs which I am calling in my post request is not relative one it is pointing to my local one

```
http://localhost:88/rty/user/user1/applications/ZZZ78R/users/409?username=ABCedit
```

so if this run on the testing environment that localhost will not be available, so please advise how should I correct my URLs in below Spock test case

```groovy
@SpringBootTest
class AuthenticationFactorControllerSpec extends Specification {
    def "Should get status 201 when server is up and post request is made"() {
        when:
        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>()
        ResponseEntity entity = new RestTemplate().postForEntity("http://localhost:88/rty/user/user1/applications/ZZZ78R/users/409?username=ABCedit", httpEntity, String.class)

        then:
        entity.statusCode == HttpStatus.CREATED
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test runner (command line, IDE, Maven/Gradle) you can set

- environment variables or
- Java system properties

which then in your test you can evaluate. For instance, one of these variables/properties could contain

- the base URL depending on the environment (local execution, development system, integration test system, acceptance test system etc.) or
- a symbolic name like "local", "development", "integration", "acceptance" and different types of environment-specific variables like URLs, user names etc. would be set depending on this variable.

I recommend a Java system property named `test.env`, `test_env` or similar in combination with a Spock base class evaluating it and setting other properties necessary for your tests. The base URL would be one of them. All your tests can extend this base class and benefit from the pre-configured properties, being able to conveniently access them during test execution whenever necessary.